# How to use HTML5 code tag to beautify code

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone have an example on how to use HTML5 `code` tag in order to display HTML code?

I tried to do that but it failed.

Afterwards, I tried to use [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/description/) but still no luck.

Any suggestions?

[Demo](http://dmsl.github.com/smartbib/)

Comment: Highlight.js is perfect for what you are looking for. What is wrong with your attempt to try it? have you seen the demos? http://softwaremaniacs.org/media/soft/highlight/test.html

Comment: Take a look at the demo. It is not working. I tried the demos. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. No error or something. Neither HTML5 or Highlight.js are working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to replace `<` tag with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`. Only by escaping these characters can you see the html code

Comment: Why "even"? This is how HTML distinguishes tags from literal angle brackets, it has nothing to do with highlighting or any other post-processing of this HTML.

Answer (score 8):

The HTML `code` tag has nothing to do with beautifying. It simply indicates its content as computer code, and by default it causes it to be rendered in a monospace font. That’s all.

To get help with beautification, I suggest that you open a new question and post your best effort so far (not links to general resources but to code that you actually tried) and explain what you wish to achieve.